# Why look at but listen to?

Tags: word-usage

Can anyone explain please why we look *at* something but listen *to* it?

Comment: Probably because we (incorrectly) think of *looking* as an action exerted upon the object being looked at, but we (correctly) understand *listening* as  passive reception.

Comment: I cannot give this as an answer, because it is a question:  Why would you expect them to be either one or the other?  Language is the outcome of natural selection, not of single decisions.  Having said that, it took the 18th century and the enlightenment for us to recognise that sight did not come from the eye to the object but was the effect of light from the object to the eye.  Moreover, sight is directional in a way that hearing is not.  We have to ‘point’ our eyes AT something.  Who knows, if humans had ears like those of dogs, we might have listened AT the radio!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no rule that will provide a simple answer. We can in fact "look to" and "listen at" but they have different meanings. For example:

(a) *Look to Windward* is a science fiction novel by Scottish writer Iain M. Banks https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_to_Windward.

(b) "My son looks to me for advice."

(c) "The burglar listened at the door to discover whether anyone was at home."

Many, many verbs in English have different meanings according to which preposition is used. As far as I know the only way to know which to use is to learn them.

Answer (score 0):

We choose to direct our gaze towards, ***at***, something.

A sound impinges on, comes ***to***, our ears, whether or not we want it to.